# Replacing an engine in a Chevy pickup ('85 K10). Is 190hp enough?

Tags: engine, chevrolet

My friend is looking to replace the engine in his older Chevy '85 K10 pickup and found this engine http://www.summitracing.com/parts/nal-10067353/overview/year/1985/make/chevrolet/model/k10.

Is the 190-250hp enough if it is a smaller truck and he is looking to just tow some smaller things, and get around without a need for a ton of speed?

In the end he will be looping in a family member that will help him with the install and is a mechanic, but we were just trying to get an idea before then. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like it can be configured for 260 HP and 350 ft/lbs torque, which, in my very limited knowledge, feels like it could be enough?

Comment: Since you haven't asked what it would be enough *for*, yes, its enough, it will move the vehicle.

Comment: I said to tow some lighter things and just general driving. To go deeper, passing on a freeway would be one example.

Comment: By what for I mean what is the trucks weight? What engine does it have now? What do you consider "small" (weight)?

Comment: Horsepower is less of an issue, where the emphasis should be put on torque output and vehicle gearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check showed that the factory 350 with a carb was rated at 175 HP, 210 if it had TBI (throttle body injection) the 190 HP crate motor should be enough. As a plus the crate motor will have a cam with a more  modern design resulting in a better running engine. While 190 HP will be enough, you have to remember that mid 80's trucks were not intended to be performance vehicles.